# Views especifica para o Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails4, devise

Em meu projeto estou utilizando o *Rails 5.1.1* e o *Devise* para login. Minha dúvida é como eu posso fazer uma View ,para que o Devise utilize como layout, sem ser a `application.html.erb`?

Comment: Você gerou as views customizadas do Devise?

Answer (score 2):

Achei a solução:

```
config.to_prepare do
    Devise::SessionsController.layout "your_layout_name"
    Devise::RegistrationsController.layout "your_layout_name"
    Devise::ConfirmationsController.layout "your_layout_name"
    Devise::UnlocksController.layout "your_layout_name"
    Devise::PasswordsController.layout "your_layout_name"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Cria um arquivo app/views/layouts/devise.html.erb e ele já será usado como layout para as views do controller devise.

Answer (score 0):

Também pode ser feito:

```
rails g devise:views user
```

E para controllers

```
rails g devise:controllers user
```

nas rotas fica:

```
sessions: 'users/sessions',
registrations: 'users/registrations'
```

Lembrando que 'user' é o modelo que é gerenciado pelo devise no seu projeto